# How do I add a scrollable list of items to an SWT messagebox?

Tags: list, swt, messagebox

I want to pop up a messagebox in SWT with a potentially long list of items.  Can I add a List widget, or should I make a new shell and populate it with a Label, List, and two Buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the MessageBox is reserved for simple messages, yes/no, OK/Cancel, things like that.

If you want to pop up a potentially long list, I would suggest creating your own dialog. That way you can customize it to look like you want it to look (including Scrollable lists)

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/List.htm) are some SWT List examples

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse ui package provides some useful dialogs for occasions like these.  Check out `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ListDialog`.